# Can someone recognize this game from a sceenshot?

Tags: game-identification

[image]

Saw this game as a screenshot on a laptop add-on screen website. Seems like a nice autochess game but I have no idea what game it is. Anyone? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The title of the game is shown at the bottom of your screenshot..

Answer (score 14):

It's [Teamfight Tactics](https://teamfighttactics.leagueoflegends.com/en-gb/):

[image]

I searched for the classes ("*game spellweaver mystic assassin skirmisher*") mentioned on the left in your screenshot. But as Wondercricket points out in a comment, it was way more obvious than that..

Answer (score -1):

From the screenshot you posted above I browed the name of the game and the title of the game Is "Teamfight tactics".
To get more on this game please do visit this site http://www.google.com/url?q=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teamfight_Tactics&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjR8ImYj4L0AhXg7XMBHVQqCcAQmhN6BAgLEBU&usg=AOvVaw1W9NWI6DHxNC14JdxTV_7z

Comment: This question has already been answered